# How to calculate depreciation on dimishing balance method using VBA Excel

Tags: vba

My code is as follows:

```
Function Depreciation(pCost As Currency, Age As Double)

    Dim cValue As Currency
    Dim Dep As Double

    Select Case Age
        Case Is < 1
            Dep = pCost
            cValue = pCost - Dep
            Depreciation = cValue

        Case Is < 2
            Dim cValue1 As Currency
            Depreciation = cValue * 0.25
            cValue1 = cValue - Depreciation
            Depreciation = cValue1

        Case Is < 3
            Dim cValue2 As Currency
            Depreciation = cValue1 * 0.25
            cValue2 = cValue1 - Depreciation
            Depreciation = cValue2
    End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the amount after depriciation, try below:

```
Option Explicit

Function Depreciation(pCost As Currency, Age As Double)
    Const DepreciationRate As Currency = 0.25
    Dim cValue As Currency, i As Double

    cValue = pCost
    i = Age
    Do Until i < 1
        cValue = cValue * (1 - DepreciationRate)
        'Debug.Print Age - i + 1, cValue ' Uncomment to see value of wach year
        i = i - 1
    Loop
    Depreciation = cValue
End Function
```